# Post JSON no Android

Tags: android, rest

Gostaria de saber se o android está sim ou não realizando o post do meu JSON.
Segue o código:

```
public void login(JSONObject dados) {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost hp = new HttpPost();

        hp.setURI(URI.create("http://10.0.2.2/restq/pages/salas"));
        hp.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        hp.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", dados.toString()));

        hp.setEntity(new StringEntity(dados.toString()));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(hp);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        String resp = new Scanner(instream, "UTF-8").next();
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(resp);

        Log.d("JSON Retorno", jo.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não consegue obter esta informação através do objeto `response`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você está fazendo uma requisição HTTP utilizando o método POST.

Para verificar o que está sendo enviado na requisição você pode utilizar algumas ferramentas, como o [RequestBin](https://requestb.in), ele coleta as informações da requisição e lhe deixa inspecionar o que está sendo enviado.

Um ponto interessante a ser notado, é que já que você não está utilizando a variável `pairs`, você poderia removê-la do seu código, ficando assim:

```
public String post(final JSONObject data) {
    try {
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();

        httpPost.setURI(URI.create("http://requestb.in/1e4rp5p1"));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(data.toString()));

        final HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
        final HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        final InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        return new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8").next();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Your tag", "Error", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Outro ponto a ser notado, é que a classe `DefaultHttpClient` está obsoleta a partir da API 22. Dito isto, eu recomendo você utilizar a classe `URLConnection`:

```
public String post(final JSONObject data) {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL("http://requestb.in/1e4rp5p1");
        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        final OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(data.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        outputStream.close();

        connection.connect();

        final InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        return new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8").next();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Your tag", "Error", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Você também pode utilizar bibliotecas para simplificar essa parte como [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp), [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) ou até mesmo [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit).

Um exemplo de utilização da biblioteca OkHttp:

```
public String post(final JSONObject data) {
    try {
        final RequestBody body = RequestBody
                .create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), data.toString());
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://requestb.in/1e4rp5p1")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .build();
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Your tag", "Error", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Lembrando que em nenhum dos exemplos acima é feita a verificação de status da requisição, e que é tratada a classe **Exception**, onde é interessante que sejam tratadas apenas as exceções específicas como **IOException**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Pedro obrigado pela ajuda.
Creio que estou fazendo algo de errado pois tentei das duas formas acima e tentei devolver o $_REQUEST do php para ver se voltava algo. Porém toda vez ele retorna vazio.

Comment: Pedro no fim das contas você me passou a resposta. Usei a biblioteca OkHttp e testei se estava enviando algo por post. O resultado foi que passou os dados por post. Ajustei o PHP pra pegar file_get_contents ao invés de $_REQUEST e funcionou.
Agradeço muito muito mesmo pela ajuda

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado! :)